# MYSQL slow query when getting total rows from another table using while loop

Tags: php, mysql

I am new to `mysql` and I am attempting to get all `ID` from another table where ID is equal to ID from `table 1` and another conditions.

Table 1

```
+---------------+
| ID model line |
+---------------+
| 1   XX    C1  |
| 2   AA    C3  |
| 3   SS    C1  |
+---------------+
```

Table 2 ( So if my query is `ID = 1 AND model = XX GROUP BY line` the total rows from table 2 will return 3 since ID 1,4 and 5 is true.

```
+----------------------------+
| ID InspectionID model line |
+----------------------------+
| 1   1            XX    C1  |
| 2   1            AA    C3  |
| 3   1            SS    C1  |
| 4   1            XX    C2  |
| 5   1            XX    C4  |
+----------------------------+
```

So far i have this query inside a PHP while loop it return what i wanted but the query is really slow.

`$query = "SELECT * FROM table2 WHERE inspectionID = '$ID' AND model = '$modelID' GROUP BY line`

So i think the best way is to join table1 and table2 and add a column total
sadly my knowledge on `mysql` and joining table is limited, any suggestions is appreciated.

my target is to create below.

```
+---------------------+
| ID model line total |
+---------------------+
| 1   XX    C1    3   |
| 2   AA    C3    0   |
| 3   SS    C1    0   |
+---------------------+
```

Comment: Why is XX line C1 total 3?  what lines from table 2 match just the 3 XX regardless of line?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pretty simple join and aggregation.  [working demo](http://rextester.com/FYJPP11979) 
 (note demo includes both answers so far and results.)

We left join so we keep all records from table 1 and join to table 2 to get records matching from table 1. We set the limit on model on the join itself so the filtering is applied to the table2 before the join occurs.  thus the count will only include model XX and all other counts for models will be zero.

```
SELECT T1.ID, T1.Model, T1.Line, count(T2.ID)
FROM table1 T1
LEFT JOIN Table2 T2
 on T1.Model = T2.Model
and T2.Model = 'XX'  
GROUP BY T1.ID, T1.Model, T1.Line
ORDER BY T1.ID
```

Answer (score 2):

Just create an [SQL View](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-views-tutorial.aspx):

```
CREATE VIEW TABLE_1_2_VIEW AS
SELECT A.id, A.model, A.line, B.inspectionID, COUNT(B.ID) Total
FROM table_1 A LEFT JOIN table_2 B
ON A.model=B.model
GROUP BY A.id, A.model, A.line, B.inspectionID
ORDER BY A.id, A.model, A.line;
```

You can query the data from this view as if it were a table.

```
SELECT id, model, line, IF(model='XX', Total, 0) Total 
FROM TABLE_1_2_VIEW
WHERE inspectionID=1;
```

Just that the data in this view would not be updatable.

Comment: Wouldn't this approach eliminate the AA and XX models from the desired results instead of showing a count of 0 for each?

Comment: @cdaiga this is my first time seeing `CREATE VIEW` the data from table 1 and table 2 is changing is this ok?

Comment: No, it won't @xQbert

Comment: @Sarotobi that is not possible.

Comment: @cdaiga I disagree: http://rextester.com/FYJPP11979  But maybe I'm missing something.

Comment: Check it again. Run `SELECT * FROM TABLE_1_2_VIEW
WHERE inspectionID=1;`. A view just grants you the flexibility to query it the way you want.

Comment: and the count for AA and SS show 1 when model 'XX' is removed.  You're welcome to play with the rextester example linked.  I don't see how you'd get 0,0 for AA and SS using this view.

Comment: I just wrote a query specifically for that! Check it again!

Comment: ok that did it; using a conditional based on XX model interesting but it works!